# Collect User Inputs in Array and Print Sorted in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to gather user inputs and sort them after the input "bye" is given. However I don't understand how to accomplish the "bye" part.
Here is what I have so far. Can someone explain why I can't add nextLine() instead of nextInt() and change things to Strings. I could then break out of the while statement with the string "bye" but none of it has worked for me so far.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Work {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] values = new int[1];
    int currentSize = 0;
    System.out.print("Type a number ");
    while( s.hasNextInt())
    {
      if(currentSize >= values.length)
      {
        values = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length + 1);
      }
      System.out.print("Type: ");
      values[currentSize] = s.nextInt();
      currentSize++;
      Arrays.sort(values);
      System.out.print(Arrays.toString( values ) );
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: What about using a condition like input is -1 or similar, or first ask for the number of elements so you won't recreate the array every time inside the `while` loop?

Comment: You should post your non working code (the one using strings)

Comment: notice your values vector has got only one value avaiable, as defined with only ONE element.

Comment: Why are you using an array when it contains just one element?

Comment: This is a problem that want's no defined array limit. As you can see it stretches the array as more inputs are added, and that's a core part of it.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain why I can't add nextLine() instead of nextInt()
>   and change things to Strings.

You can, you just have to handle the conversions.

```
String input = null;
while(!"bye".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
{
    value = Integer.parseInt(input.trim());

    //..do stuff with the int value

    input = s.nextLine();
}
```

You may need to handle `NumberFormatException` if you don't want to trust that the user will enter numbers.

Comment: Yes but how do you handle the case in which the input does equal bye?

Comment: When the user enters "bye", the loop exits. Isn't that what you want? "Handle the case" would be any code after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer posted by James is appropriate!

Although, if you want to exit the loop when user enters "bye" and use the **nextLine()** then here is another solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] values = new int[1];
    int currentSize = 0;
    System.out.print("Type a number ");

    while (s.hasNext()) {

        // assign it to local var
        String input = s.nextLine();

        // check for bye
        if (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
            if (currentSize >= values.length) {
                values = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length + 1);
            }
            System.out.print("Type: ");
            // add the input value.
            values[currentSize] = Integer.parseInt(input.trim());
            currentSize++;
            Arrays.sort(values);
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(values));
        } else {
            System.out.println("exiting...");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

This one adds some branching in code for user input string comparison using if-else loop.
Hope it helps!